# Sed command in bash script

Tags: bash

I work with bash script . I have simple text

```
22
80
880
```

and I want to get this "22,80,880" using .Can enybody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simplest approach is to use [the `tr` ("translate characters") utility](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/7908799/xcu/tr.html), telling it to translate newlines to commas:

```
tr '\n' , < input_file > output_file
```